# How to set persian font name in openxml spreadsheet c#

Tags: c#, openxml, spreadsheet

I'm unable to set persian font names for openxml spreadsheet, English fonts are ok but none english not. (openxml 2.13)

```
        new Fonts(
        new Font( // Index 0 - The default font.
        new FontSize() { Val = 11 },
        new Color() { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "FF0000" } },
        new FontName { Val = "B Nazanin" }),
```

Comment: And what happens instead?

Comment: font name is changed in excel but it will not get effect on cells